# Full tank ? empty tank ? frequent fills? What about EV

Tags: battery, electric-vehicle

Sure it is agreed by most to not drive a petrol car on empty ,This is also true for lithium powered EV.Also for EV it is not so good to drive on 100% charge .If your application involves a very small range like 10% of the stated range then where are the best charge and discharge points ?  60% 50% ? 80% 70% ? what would give the best battery life ?

Answer (score 2):

[Qmerit's recommendation](https://qmerit.com/blog/maintaining-battery-health-with-ev-charging-best-practices/) is:

> Lithium-ion batteries work better when they are used and charged in partial cycles, in other words, not completely depleted or fully charged.

> Consequently, the best charging practice is to charge the battery at different stages, optimally **keeping its level between 20% and 80%**.

The reasons they state this is fairly simple:

- Continually draining your battery to 0% usefulness or charging it up to 100% when it isn't needed can cause damage to the battery.
- If you leave the charge at 80% max, this would leave room for regenerative braking to refill the battery if needed. (I can imagine this would only happen if you live on a large hill).

[This article in Wired magazine](https://www.wired.com/story/how-to-take-care-electric-vehicle-battery/) tends to agree with this recommendation. Their article has information in it gleaned from [Qichao Hu](https://scholar.harvard.edu/qichaohu/biocv), who has been studying rechargeable batteries for quite some time.

Comment: One may find that the vehicle automatically manages the eighty percent maximum unless operator-overridden. Our ten year old EV will charge to that level, although I can execute a series of button presses on the charge panel display to perform a one hundred percent charge. This action is accompanied by an alert message that doing so repeatedly will cause battery degradation. Additionally, for other use batteries, i.e., lawn equipment, scooters, etc., it is recommended to not charge to one hundred percent and leave the battery idle.

Comment: @Paulster2 .Your answer is correct +1 .What about ave  battery charge? where between 20 and 80 or does it not matter?

Comment: @Autistic - From what I've read, it really doesn't matter. For practicality sake, I'd suggest the higher side is better just to ensure you have as much range as possible at any given time. It is better to have the extra charge and not need it, versus the alternative.

Comment: In the past, I read on the Battery University web site that lithium batteries are happiest at 50% charge, so as close as you can keep it there, the better for the battery, but maybe not for you. It seems like for lots of short trips, maybe 40 - 60 is good, or even 45 -55 if the trips are real short, and higher if anticipating a longer drive.